# Asp.net grdiview: can i format the dataitems in an itemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formatting

i have this code in an itemtemplate in a gridview:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "DiscountAmount")%>
```

It's a decimal value, and it shows 20.300000000000, which is technically right, but i'd prefer to show 20.30 or 20,30, depending on the culture.

But i've never been a big fan of gridviews, and the `DataBinder.Eval`  and `Container.DataItem` haven't been good friends either, and i'm lost with how to use it.

it has a special prefix (<%#) and when i type anything other then the original code it's no good, but changing <%# to <%= or <% doesn't seem to work either?

Comment: [See Here for complete solution with example](http://www.codeshower.blogspot.in/2012/10/datetime-format-in-gridview.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also work:

```
<%#= String.Format("{0, 0:N2}",DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "DiscountAmount"))%>
```

**Edit**: I share your discomfort with declarative databinding syntax. **You can accomplish the same thing in code-behind** by calling the `RowDataBound` event and implementing whatever changes you want to make as the data is bound to the `GridViewRow`.

To do this, you need to wire up the event in the markup by setting `OnRowDataBound` to the name of your event handler, something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="InvoiceGrid" OnRowDataBound="InvoiceGrid_RowDataBound".....>
```

Then you create an event handler in code behind with a signature like this:

```
protected void InvoiceGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

The first thing you do in that event handler is test which type of `GridViewRow` type it is:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)....
```

Then you do whatever formatting you want to do.

For folks happy with declarative markup, this may seem burdensome. But for people who are comfortable writing code, you can do a whole lot more here in code behind.

Comment: and then get the control with findcontrol on the e?

Comment: Yes, FindControl or you can cheat and do e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "some text" but that'll break if you change the columns. Check this out for some more ideas http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/ui/webcontrols/GridViewClassRowDataBound.aspx

Comment: just make sure to write it inside you client-side code like that: 
<asp:Label ID="LblTest" runat="server"><%# String.Format("{0, 0:N2}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COLUMN_NAME"))%></asp:Label>

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
<%= String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "DiscountAmount"))%>
```

or just

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DiscountAmount", "{0:0,0.00}")
```

You can read more format options in the article [String Format for Double](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/).

Comment: This should work also: `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DiscountAmount", "{0:0,0.00}") %>` (i.e, just call the overloaded function).

Comment: And how would i do this with a cultureinfo?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways...some of them stated above and here is another one:

```
Text='<%# GetFormattedDiscount(Eval("DiscountAmount").ToString())%>'
```

GetFormattedDiscout is a function in your code-behind where you can do whatever formatting you need and return it as string:

```
protected void GetFormattedDiscount(string amount){
return String.Format("{0:N2}",amount);
}
```

Even this should work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#String.Format("{0:n2}",Eval("DiscountAmount")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```